# jQuery Mobile Icons not fitting buttons properly

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm busy developing a jQuery Mobile App and for some reason the buttons keep appearing like so:

[image]

Here is my code that produces these buttons:

```
   <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="home" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" data-mini="true" >Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#searchpage" data-icon="search" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" data-mini="true" >Search</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#sellbookpage" data-icon="dollar" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Sell</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contactus" data-icon="email" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is there a way to have the icons appear in the middle of the button? Or does anyone know the reason for this to be possibly happening?

Comment: Happens on all browsers? Are you overriding JQM styles? What version of jquery and jquery mobile are you using?

Comment: Once again thanks for the help Omar

Answer (score 0):

I was using another icons image package. After looking at the css sheet and removing the following line:

```
margin-top:-10px !important;
```

Everything started working fine.